Winter Bash 2020 LEGO Prizes!
Happy holidays everyone! Bricks Stack Exchange is once again participating in the Winter Bash celebration with the rest of the Stack Exchange network!

There are a few different ways to win prizes this year. All winners will get a set of their choosing worth up to 100 EUR.

2 winners will be selected randomly from everyone who earns at least 5 hats. Progress can be checked on the Bricks leaderboard.
1 winner will be selected for the best submission to the building competition.
1 winner will be selected randomly from the other submissions to the building competition.

Thanks go to TLG for supporting this activity by providing prizes for us!
All winners will need to provide me with a shipping address within 1 week of the end of the competition, or their prize will be forfeited. This contest is unfortunately not open to residents of Iran, North Korea, Myanmar/Burma, Zimbabwe, Sudan, Syria, and any other U.S. sanctioned country and where prohibited or restricted by law. This is a legal requirement that is outside of both our control and The LEGO Group's control.
The goal here is to facilitate positive engagement on the site both to celebrate the holidays and because this is the time of year when we get a lot of new traffic from parents and others just getting into LEGO. My hope is that providing prizes for this will facilitate meaningful engagement on the site. Please don't make a mess of things just to earn hats. :)
Good luck and have fun!

Will everybody get the same amount of “votes” in the raffle, or will you use a pro-rating system like the one proposed after last year’s Winter Bash? I proposed giving everyone with at least 5 hats one entry into the raffle, and then adding entries for every 3?/5? additional hats attained.

@PhilB. The plan for this year is to simply give each person with over 5 hats one entry into the drawing. This is somewhat logistically simpler for me, and also removes any incentive at all for folks to go overboard collecting hats. If folks are looking for more chances to win, we do have the building competition available.
